# Code optimisation ideas

Tags: python, optimization

I wrote a code in Python that print a Fibonacci sequence truncated at a given threshold.

```
m_char=input('threshold: ')
m=int(m_char)

def fibonacci(m):
    lst=[0, 1]
    while lst[-1] <= m:
        a = lst[-2]+lst[-1]
        if a <= m:
            lst.append(a)
        else:
            print(lst)
            return

fibonacci(m)
```

I don't like the double check on the variable `m` in the `while` and `if` statement: I'm pretty sure it is redundant, so there is a way to write more efficient code. I would like to preserve the use of lists. Have you got any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def fibonacci(m):
    lst=[0, 1]
    a = lst[-2]+lst[-1]
    while a <= m:
        lst.append(a)
        a = lst[-2]+lst[-1]
    return lst
```

You can calculate `a` once per loop, and use it to determine the whether the loop continues

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
while True:
```

it is the check inside the loop which actually determines how often the loop is run.

It would be slightly more efficient to not use list indexing at all but instead maintain the last two Fibonacci numbers with two variables. Furthermore, it is more idiomatic to *return* the list rather than print it. Let the calling code print the list if it wants:

```
def fibonacci(m):
    lst=[0, 1]
    a,b = lst
    while True:
        a,b = b, a+b
        if b <= m:
            lst.append(b)
        else:
            return lst
```